# Can I store a file in "memory" with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io

I'm doing some file manipulation work with node.js and many of the packages that I use require a "path" to be sent so that they can open the file, do some work, and so on.

But I'm parsing millions of files and rather than actually store them on disk, I'd like to store them in memory. The contents of the files are all in my database and I'd hate to write them to disk, just to do my insanely awesome work on them.

So is such a thing possible?

Comment: you could copy the file in /dev/shm (or /tmp if its tmpfs) when starting, then persisting back the final result

Comment: This sound like caching, a quick search led me to this? https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-cache. In addition to @guido 's answer, write it to a tmp directive. The problem with using packages that require a "path" is that they have been implemented using I/O libraries. So to use a memory solution, you would also hafto avoid these libraries.

Comment: I don't know the size of your files ,but for sure you will not able to store completely all your data in the memory (RAM).

Comment: If the `fs` module is involved, which is likely given the requirement of a `path`, then they need to be files in an accessible file system. You should be able to use a virtual disk or in-memory fs, such as [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs). But, unless the database can pretend to be a file system itself, you'll have to write them out. Or, find alternate methods or packages that work with Streams or Buffers rather than paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a Linux system then you can merely create your own tmpfs (RAM) via the following nodejs code. This creates a tmpfs at /mnt/myramdisk as per the node code. The directory /mnt/myramdisk must be manually created beforehand obviously via mkdir /mnt/myramdisk.

```
var MountPoint='/mnt/myramdisk';
var TextFile='/MyTextFileInRAM.txt';
var RAM_Size='512m';

const fs = require('fs');

const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec("awk '{print $2}' /proc/mounts | grep "+MountPoint, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    // node couldn't execute the command
    //console.log(err);
    console.log(MountPoint+' is Not Mounted yet. Im mounting it now:\n');
    NotMountedYetSoMountIt();
    return;
  }
  // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
  if(stdout)
    {
        console.log(MountPoint+' is Already Mounted');
        TextToWriteToFileOnTMPFS();
    } 
});

function NotMountedYetSoMountIt()
{
    const { exec } = require('child_process');
    exec('df -h && echo && mount -t tmpfs -o size='+RAM_Size+' tmpfs '+MountPoint+' && echo && df -h', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        // node couldn't execute the command
        return;
      }
    // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    TextToWriteToFileOnTMPFS();
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    });
}

function TextToWriteToFileOnTMPFS()
{

    let TextToWrite = 'Hello\n' + 
                      'world @'+CurrentTime();

    fs.writeFile(MountPoint+TextFile, TextToWrite, (err) => {
        // throws an error, you could also catch it here
        if (err) throw err;
        // success case, the file was saved
        console.log('saved!');
    });
}

function addZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}
function CurrentTime()
{
  var d = new Date();
  var h = addZero(d.getHours());
  var m = addZero(d.getMinutes());
  var s = addZero(d.getSeconds());
  return h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}
```

Output:

```
root@box:/daemons#node tmpfs_test.js && cat /mnt/myramdisk/MyTextFileInRAM.txt
/mnt/myramdisk is Not Mounted yet. Im mounting it now:

stdout: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.4M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       938G  436G  454G  49% /
tmpfs           7.8G  449M  7.4G   6% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8213
/dev/sda1       511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/loop2       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268


Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.4M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       938G  436G  454G  49% /
tmpfs           7.8G  449M  7.4G   6% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8213
/dev/sda1       511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/loop2       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
tmpfs           512M     0  512M   0% /mnt/myramdisk

stderr:
saved!
Hello
world @23:09:15



root@box:/daemons# node tmpfs_test.js && cat /mnt/myramdisk/MyTextFileInRAM.txt
/mnt/myramdisk is Already Mounted
saved!
Hello
world @23:09:19
```

Answer (score 13):

It looks like it's possible look at this article how to do it [creating writable memory stream](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-19-nodejs-writable-streams.html#creating_writable_memory_stream)

Comment: But what do I pass to packages that need a file path?

Comment: Create a temporary file then delete

Comment: Look for alternate libraries that are more stream-friendly.

Comment: Was hoping to not get that answer @Joe

Comment: Well - if a library author makes the shortsighted mistake to assume a specific type of input and output and not write to the appropriate abstraction, then your choices are somewhat limited.

Comment: I'd suggest adding at least a basic segment of code to your answer rather than leaving this as a link.

Comment: Sucks pretty much that this is so underdeveloped. Creating files instead of using buffers, streams or pipes for server side processes is just both slow and ugly. Since Node has all these things, module developers should allow for this flexibility.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`memfs`](https://github.com/streamich/memfs), which is an in-memory filesystem for Node.js.

Comment: very interesting, looks exactly like the built-in "fs"

Answer (score 5):

Maybe create a `Buffer` using `let myBuffer = Buffer.from(fetchedData)` after fetching each file from the database then using `myBuffer.toString()` to change the file to a string and parse/manipulate it however you like

Answer (score 4):

Because I have not found a single library that suited my needs, I have created [diskette](https://github.com/samvv/diskette). It is a tiny library that tries to efficiently store data such as buffers and strings and make it streamable. I use it in my own projects and so far it works like a charm.

- [NPM](http://npmjs.com/package/diskette)
- [GitHub](http://github.com/samvv/diskette)

Please let me know if you found a bug or if there's anything more that can be added to it.

Comment: Since the GitHub repository no longer exists, perhaps this answer should be deleted?

Comment: If I find the time I'll re-upload the GitHub repo